# Lists in markdown

Tags: markdown, syntax

Suppose I have a list something like -

```
1. some content 

2. some content 

2b . some content 

2c. some content 

3. some content
```

Now if I were to parse in markdown way it comes out as -

1. 2. some content
   3. some content

   2b . some content

   2c. some content

Update - I have been supplying the numbers manually but still it doesn't get rendered right :(

```
3. some content
```

As can be seen the markdown syntax gets completely screwed. How can I put it the way I want it ?

Comment: Something worth remembering is there's different 'flavours' of markdown. There's been attempts at standardising it [like gruber's original specification](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) or [commonmark](http://commonmark.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Insert one space character before 2b. and 2c. to indent those lines, and two spaces at the end of each line before pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to start a new line.

1. some content
2. some content
   2b. some content
   2c. some content
3. some content

Press the gray *edit* link under this answer to show the unrendered markdown text.
This also doesn't change the numbering of the lines in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Markdown doesn't understand a,b,c, you may want to use it like

```
 1. some content
 2. some content
     1. some content
     2. some content
 3. some content
```

which will be rendered to

1. some content
2. some content

   1. some content
   2. some content
3. some content

Another way if you still want to use a,b,c you may want to use un-ordered list but then you need manually supply your numbers

```
 - 1) some content
 - 2) some content
   - 2b)  some content
   - 2c)  some content
 - 3) some content
```

that rendered to

- 1) some content
- 2) some content

  - 2b)  some content
  - 2c)  some content
- 3) some content

---

Answer (score 0):

Markdown can be 'forced' into making sublists, use 2 spaces at the end of a line then carriage return, to force a new line.
So this

```
1. some content
1. some content  
1a. some content  
4b. some content  
1. some content
```

becomes this

1. some content
2. some content
   1a. some content
   4b. some content
3. some content

See how it will set the numbered points itself, but not for the a & b sections, they must be numbered specifically. I have intentionally 'broken' the numbering there to show this.

BTW, Stack Exchange uses markdown to format the questions & answers, so you can practise to your heart's content in any question or answer editor here & see live how it will look.